# How to count unique values on one column without double values from another column

Tags: mysql, sql

My very first question as a newb in SQL.

I want to count unique values from one column `Transport`, group them by `ID` and delete double values in the `Transport` column that may be caused by `Product` column. Could be very simple, but at this point I need another point of view.

This is the data

| ID | Product | Transport |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Plane |
| 1 | B | Plane |
| 2 | A | Train |
| 2 | B | Train |
| 2 | C | Ship |
| 3 | A | Plane |
| 3 | B | Train |
| 3 | C | Ship |
| 3 | D | Ship |

I would want to have the `ID` as unique values and then count each of the unique values of the `Transport`. If I do it with a normal GROUP BY, the `Products` will double the counting.

The result I need has to count each of the `Transport` values in separated columns without being doubled by the `Product` column. So it should look something like:

| ID | Plane | Train | Ship |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I think it's simple but maybe I'm missing something. Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: The way I would do it would require PIVOT function. Does your version support that function?

Comment: Seems like you just want to indicate if a certain ID was transported at least once with plane, ship, or train?

Comment: How come 'ship' is 0 0 1. Ship exists for both id = 2 and 3?

Comment: @Josh it does support it! Just out of curiosity, how would you do it with way?

Comment: @derpirscher exactly, without counting it double from each Product.

Comment: @Pankaj that's my bad, a typo: so it should be ID 2, train = 1, ship = 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a pivot by combining `CASE` with `MAX()`, as in:

```
select
  id,
  max(case when transport = 'Plane' then 1 else 0 end) as plance,
  max(case when transport = 'Train' then 1 else 0 end) as train,
  max(case when transport = 'Ship' then 1 else 0 end) as ship
from t
group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding something to @The Impater's result

```
SELECT
  id,
  MAX(transport = 'Plane') AS plance,
  MAX(transport = 'Train') AS train,
  MAX(transport = 'Ship')  AS ship
FROM `test_table`
GROUP BY id
```

I was taught there is no need to assign 1 and 0 when it can be done via boolean-type logic as results are returned either in 0 or 1.

Comment: Thank you Asgar, I used @The Impaler's option because yours gave me an error after the ')' before 'AS' 

Incorrect syntax near ')'. Expecting ',', AND, or OR

Comment: @indie_cloud, I have tried your data with MySQL 5.6. I don't think there is an issue with the query